# How to remove duplicate object from an array in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular2-services

I am trying to remove duplicate value objects in an array but not working... I think duplicate function is working but not reflecting in `li` list. Can you find out where I have to change?

My service file:

```
 addComp(Names,c){   
 this.item.push({ name: Names, componentid: c});
 this.uniqueArray = this.removeDuplicates(this.item, "name"); //this line issue
 this.item=this.uniqueArray; //this line issue
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `addComp` is the only place you modify `this.item`, just check for existing prior to insertion. Duplicates will never get put in the array, so you'll never have to trim them.

```
addComp(Names,c){
  let item = {name: Names, componentid: c};
  if (this.item.find((test) => test.name === Names) === undefined) {
    this.item.push(item);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if there are other places that you're modifying `this.item`, you should be stripping duplicates in a more expected place. Stripping them as a side-effect of the `addComp` function is unexpected. However, you could do it...

```
addComp(Names,c){
  this.item.push({name: Names, componentid: c});
  this.item = this.item.filter((test, index, array) =>
     index === array.findIndex((findTest) =>
        findTest.name === test.name
     )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Working fine

Comment: I have some question in angular 6..Can you answer me?

Answer (score 21):

```
const result = Array.from(this.item.reduce((m, t) => m.set(t.name, t), new Map()).values());
```

This might be fix your issue.

Answer (score 12):

```
this.item = this.item.filter((el, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(el))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove existing duplicates in `this.item`

```
const item = [...new Set(this.item)];
```

This is a more updated way to do this. this will check for existing prior to insertion. And if `item` is not in `this.item` then `this.item.indexOf(item) = -1`

This is the best way to prevent pushing duplicate value objects in to an array

```
addComp(Names,c){
  let item = {name: Names, componentid: c};
  if (this.item.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    this.item.push(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the bug

```
const uniqueObjectArray = [...new Map(arrayOfObjectsWithDuplicates.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you have an array:

```
var ar = [ 
{key: 1, value: 'aa'},
{key: 2, value: 'bb'},
{key: 1, value: 'aa'},
]
```

To filter it and eliminate duplicates based on a key, use the following:

```
ar.filter((el, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(a.find(f => f.key === el.key)))
```