# Filter array to remove duplicate values based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an array with dulipacte values

```js
let myArray=[
    {name: "apple", cost: "10"},
    {name: "apple", cost: "20"},
    {name: "bannana", cost: "10"},
    {name: "mango", cost: "20"},
    {name: "apple", cost: "5"},
    {name: "mango", cost: "50"}
    {name: "orange", cost: "30"}
]
```

and i want to remove duplicates whose cost is low...expected output to be...

```js
let myArray=[
    {name: "apple", cost: "20"},
    {name: "bannana", cost: "10"},
    {name: "mango", cost: "50"}
    {name: "orange", cost: "30"}
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637425/how-to-remove-duplicate-object-from-an-array-in-angular-6

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired result, we create an object / map with a property for each product name.

If the product stored in the map is of a lower cost *or* does not exist we replace as we enumerate through the list of products.

We then use Object.values to turn back into an array.

```js
let myArray = [
    {name: "apple", cost: "10"},   
    {name: "apple", cost: "20"},
    {name: "bannana", cost: "10"},
    {name: "mango", cost: "20"},
    {name: "apple", cost: "5"},
    {name: "mango", cost: "50"},
    {name: "orange", cost: "30"}
]

let result = myArray.reduce((res, product) => { 
    
    if (!res[product.name]) {
        // The product does not exist in the map, add it
        res[product.name] = product;
    } else if (Number(res[product.name].cost) < Number(product.cost)) { 
        // A cheaper product exists, replace it. 
        res[product.name] = product;
    }
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```